# Exact Cochran's Q test in R

Tags: r, statistics, statistical-test

I need to run a Cochran's test with small sample sizes. I read that "If your sample size is inadequate, the asymptotic p-value may not be accurate, but you can run an "exact" version of Cochran's Q test that will generate a more accurate exact p-value" ([here](https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/cochrans-q-test-in-spss-statistics.php)).

The "[nonpar](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nonpar/nonpar.pdf)" package for R offers different tests and in many cases there is the option `exact= TRUE` which can be used if one wants to avoid approximation. However, there is no such option for the `cochrans.q()` function. How can I know whether an approximation or exact approach is used in `cochrans.q()`?

I am unsure whether to post the question here or on Cross Validated. So please migrate the question if it should go to SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses the asymptotic approximation. It can be seen in the source code of (just type `cochrans.q`) as it contains

```
p = 1 - pchisq(Q, df)
```